multiplot in for loop by importing only pandas
Sometime, DataFrame.plot() inside a for loop produces multiple charts.
import pandas as pd

data = {'Str': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B'], 'Num': [i for i in range(4)]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
for n in ['A', 'B']:
  df[df.Str == n].plot(kind='bar')


But sometimes, it produces a single chart.
import pandas as pd

data = {'C1': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B'], 
        'C2': [i for i in range(4)],
        'C3': [1,2,1,2]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
for n in [1,2]:
  df[df.C3 == n].groupby('C1').C2.sum().plot(kind='bar')


From the previous code, if plt.show() was added at the end of the loop.  It will produce multiple charts.
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


data = {'C1': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B'], 
        'C2': [i for i in range(4)],
        'C3': [1,2,1,2]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
for n in [1,2]:
  df[df.C3 == n].groupby('C1').C2.sum().plot(kind='bar')
  plt.show()


I don't want to use plt.show().  Actually I want to import only pandas and create multiple charts using a for loop.

It's almost certainly because in the second example the x axis is the same for both plots, so the second plot's data overwrites the first.

I thought about that too.  However, in @mozway's answer, the x axis is the same for both plots but the code can produce multiple charts.

Indeed it looks like mozway figured out the reason (being series vs. dataframe). Useful to know for future reference.

I'm not sure why matplotlib behave this way, but your code in the second loop products a Series while the first produces a DataFrame. This might force reusing the same axes.
You could add as_index=False in the groupby to have an object that is comparable to the one in the first loop:
for n in [1,2]:
  df[df.C3 == n].groupby('C1', as_index=False).C2.sum().plot(kind='bar')

Output:


Also note that (explicitly) importing matplotlib should not be an issue. It is already a dependency of pandas and will be imported by pandas anyway, therefore not importing it won't cause any gain in the code.

Thank very much for your answer.  pandas plots one chart if Series is plotted in a loop but do multiple plot for DataFrame.  From your idea, I modified the second code to do multiple plot df[df.C3 == n].groupby('C1').C2.sum().to_frame().plot(kind='bar').

@wannik you're welcome. I forgot to mention in my answer but you can also leverage groupby for your loop, which will be more efficient than repeated indexing: for k, g in df.groupby('C3', as_index=False, sort=False): g.groupby('C1').C2.sum().to_frame().plot(kind='bar') or if you want specific values: g = df.groupby('C3', as_index=False, sort=False) ; for x in [1, 2]: g.get_group(x).groupby('C1').C2.sum().to_frame().plot(kind='bar')

if you don want import matplotlib and import seaborn, make result to dataframe and use plot function with subplots=True
# example code
import pandas as pd

data = {'C1': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B'], 
        'C2': [i for i in range(4)],
        'C3': [1,2,1,2]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# plot code
df.groupby(['C3', 'C1'])['C2'].sum().unstack(0).plot(kind='bar', subplots=True)


However, if I were you, I would probably use matplotlib or seaborn, unless there are special circumstances that prevent you from installing those libraries.
